# Convert arbitrary grid of subpixel points to raster image

Tags: c++, math, rendering, pixel, vector-graphics

I hope you are doing well. I am stuck at one part of a visual effect program in C++, and wanted to ask for help.

I have an array of colors at random positions on an image. There can be any number of these "subpixels" that fall over top of any given pixel. The subpixels that overlap a pixel can be at any position within the pixel, since they're distributed randomly throughout the image. All I have access to is their position on the image and their color, which represents what the color should be at that precise subpixel point on the image.

I need to determine what color to make each pixel of the image. In other words, I need to interpolate what the color should be at the centre of each pixel.

Here is a diagram with an example of this on a 5x5 image:

I need to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

If it aids your understanding, you can think of the first image as a series of random points whose color values were calculated using bilinear interpolation on the second image.

I am writing this in C++, and ideally it will be as fast as possible, but I welcome contributions in any language or just explained with symbols or words. It should be as accurate as possible, but I also welcome solutions that are slightly inaccurate in favour of performance or simplicity.

Please let me know if you need clarification on the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain English. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not sure I understand your comment. I can't "write down a step-by-step process of doing this" as I have no idea how to do it. I'm looking for an approach to solving this problem, whether someone prefers to express it in code or in theory. I've already spent lots of time seeking solutions by talking out loud to myself, and after that failed to produce anything useful, I decided to come on here to see if anyone could help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you know cell size/grid dimension (5x5 here)?

Comment: On X-Y-Color(Hue?) 3D coordinate system, fit a plane to the data points. And then, resample the color values at center position of each grid cells.

Comment: For a simple solution just take the 'average' colour of all points falling into each cell.   Whether this is a good solution to your problem is for you to decide.

Comment: @MBo Yes I do. Typically it will be a 1080p or 4k image.

Comment: @fana This looks like it could be the optimal solution, although I'm not sure if it will be fast enough for my purposes. I'll give it a try; Thank you!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately when I tried this I found that it wasn't accurate enough, presumably because, due to the random distribution of known points, there can be pixels/cells with a cluster of points in one corner and none/few in the rest of the pixel, so averaging the points will produce a very wrong color for that cell.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding quite a decent solution which, while it doesn't find the absolutely 100% technically correct color for each pixel, was more than good enough and acceptably fast, especially when I added multithreading.

I first create a vector for each pixel/cell that contains pointers to subpixels (points with known colors). When I create a subpixel, I add a pointer to it to the vector representing the pixel/cell that it overlaps *and* to each of the vectors representing pixels/cells directly adjacent to the pixel/cell that that it overlaps.

Then, I split each pixel/cell into *n* sub-cells (I found 8 works well). This is not as expensive as you might imagine, because I only have to calculate & compare the distance for those subpixels that are in that pixel/cell's subpixel pointer vector. For each sub-cell, I calculate which subpixel is the closest to its centre. That subpixel's color then contributes 1/*n*th of the color for that pixel/cell.

I found it was important to add the subpixel pointers to adjacent cell/pixel vectors, so that each sub-cell can take into account subpixels from adjacent pixels/cells. This even makes it produce a reasonable color when there are pixels/cells that have no subpixels overlapping them (as long as the neighboring pixels/cells do).

Thanks for all the comments so far; any ideas about how to speed this up would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Anyone looking for a perfectly accurate method might find this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QT5MVtYS68o (there are some C++ implementations of this method on Github if you search for "scattered data interpolation")